# android library module dependency version conflict with app module

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have developed an android library module. This module is using some dependencies (eg: `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.2.2`).

This module should be reused used in older application which has some older versions of that dependencies (okhttp in version 3.12). It will be just included as source code. Not as `aar`.

Including my module to this application will make gradle to resolve the dependencies tree and use only the newest versions of the same library. But I want to be able to use these newest versions only in the module and not expose them to the main application module. Is it somehow possible?

Thanks in advance